# What would cause a deferred object to be rejected?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

I think I'm going about this the wrong way. This is what I'm trying to do instead of using RequireJS or LABjs:

```
var APP = {};
APP._timers = {};
APP._timelines = {};

$.when(
    $.getScript('/app/models/Timer.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/models/Section.js'),

    $.getScript('/app/collections/Timers.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/collections/Sections.js'),

    $.getScript('/app/views/SectionView.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/views/APPView.js'),

    $.Deferred(function(deferred){
        $(deferred.resolve);
    })
).done(function () {
    alert('done');
    console.log(APP.APPView);
    var foo = new APP.APPView;
    APP._timelines.main = new APP.Timers('main');
    APP._timelines.branched = new APP.Timers('branched');
}).fail(function(){
    alert('failed');
});
```

It is alerting `failed`, nothing is being written to the console.

If I open up any of those files, say `APPView.js` and alert something at the top or bottom of the file, I see it appear. Here's an example of that file:

```
APP.APPView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $("#app-view"),
    initialize : function () {
        alert('App view initialized'); // Never gets called
        this.sectionVew = new APP.SectionView();
    }
});
alert('Inside APPView.js'); // gets called
```

Comment: After your `alert('fail');` put something like: `console.log(arguments)` and you might find it is returning you details about the problem?

Comment: Why are you creating a Deferred that immediately resolves itself?

Comment: @JohnFlatness It is resolving when the DOMReady event happens or immediately if it already has.

Comment: @KevinB Ah, I see, I skimmed right over the `$()` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the reason why this is failing is because you try to load all your scripts inside `$.when` without managing dependencies. Each of the `$.getScript` is async and they do not necessary complete in order. Hence if your view loads before your model execution will stop when it will try to use the undefined model.
In short, to do this you would have to either:

1. manage the dependencies manually. i.e. once the model is loaded, THEN load the view.
2. write trully independent modules
3. and this is the simplest, stop trying to manually do all that and use an AMD loader such as require.js. This is the reason why it's there!

Comment: You're right, one of my dependencies wasn't getting loaded in time. I have to give credit to James Khoury from the comments above who told me to `console.log(arguments)` which pointed out my undefined function error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the implementation of your domReady deferred, try it this way:

```
var APP = {};
APP._timers = {};
APP._timelines = {};

var domRdyDeferred = $.Deferred();
$(domRdyDeferred.resolve);

$.when(
    $.getScript('/app/models/Timer.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/models/Section.js'),

    $.getScript('/app/collections/Timers.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/collections/Sections.js'),

    $.getScript('/app/views/SectionView.js'),
    $.getScript('/app/views/APPView.js'),

    domRdyDeferred
).done(function () {
    alert('done');
    console.log(APP.APPView);
    var foo = new APP.APPView;
    APP._timelines.main = new APP.Timers('main');
    APP._timelines.branched = new APP.Timers('branched');
}).fail(function(){
    console.log(arguments);
    alert('failed');
});
```

It is important to note though that they may not complete in the order that you add them to `$.when`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the idea for the deferred DOM ready handler from http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2124-Using-Deferred-Objects-As-An-Asynchronous-Script-Loader-In-jQuery-1-5.htm

Comment: Ah, I remember that post! His newest post may be useful for this too. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm